# append content in a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scripting

I'm trying to insert some content in a defined function, something like this:

```
var f = function(){
   alert("Hello");
};

var e = function(){
   alert('Hey');
};
    f = f + e;
f();
```

the output will be: "Hello", and then another alert with "Hey".

Is it possible to do something like this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I could imagine (but the question is whether it makes much sense) is something like this:

```
function combine() {
    var func = arguments;
    return function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < func.length; i++) {
            if(typeof func[i] == 'function') {
                func[i]();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
f = combine(f,e);
f();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YDgqv/)

But this is just executing the functions one after another, you don't have access to variables declared in other functions, and return values are lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass one function into another as an argument, which can call its function parameter.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ybNu9/

```
var f = function( fn ){
   alert("Hello");
   fn();
};

var e = function(){
   alert('Hey');
};

f( e );
```

Of course, this requires the anticipation of such a parameter in the `f` function.

Comment: You could do it the other way around, have `e` call `f`, and avoid previous knowledge in `f`.

Comment: @Juan - Very true, though `e` would need previous knowledge of `f`. It would be helpful to know more about OP's actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

no, it is against any "normal" programming convention. Writing a=f+e would concatenate their return values, that is all you could do to at least simulate behaviour you want. Writing f=f+e is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "insert" code into a function, I suppose the closest you can do is re-define the original function, for example:

```
var old_f = f;
f = function() { old_f(); alert('Hey'); };
```

Though...I can't think of a generic *good* reason to do this (there's a better solution in most cases), can you not run an additional function, or call both?  for example:

```
function newFunc() { f(); e(); }
```